# Calling a test suite from another Test Suite/Test Case

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, katalon

As per my project requirement I need a Test Suite to be called from another Test Suite, is this anyhow possible in Katalon Studio? There is an inbuilt function for calling Test Cases but there isn't any for calling Test Suites. I would be of great help if someone helped me with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could just split the calling suite into *pre* and *post* steps.

Then your runner could run

1. Pre Suite
2. The Test Suite you wanted to call
3. Post Suite.